# PowerShell Input file format

Tags: powershell, csv, input

I actually wanted to ask your advice on the best format for an input file.

In the past I always used the CSV-format with `import-CSV`. But as you can see in the example below (delete all files older than x days) it's quite tedious to decipher all the lines. Big chunks of code barely readable but working just fine :P

Now I've been asked to create a new script (copy from one folder to another) and it needs an input file to. For example you might decide later on to add some more switches to the input file. Or leave specific switches empty.

How would you guys handle the input file? Or what way do you format input files in general for easy deciphering later on in the script?

As always, thank you for your advice.

**Example input file:**

```
# Input formats:
#
# [SERVER,]PATH[,OlderThanDays][ ,k]
# MailTo: [user1@domain.com] [user2@domain.com] [..]
#
# - PATH > Path to a file or folder that can be a UNC-path, local path on the script server or a local path on the remote server if you specify [SERVER, ]
# - [] > Fields between these brackets are optional
# - OlderThanDays > Nothing provided, a default of 30 days will be used
#                 > 0, zero means all files and folders will be deleted
# - k > If provided we don't do anything with folders, by default we will delete all empty folders regardless of their creation date
# - [SERVER] > Can be the name of the server or the name of the local host. Must have OS Windows Server 2008 R2 or Windows 7 at least, otherwise use UNC-path
# - MailTo:  > Contains the mail addresses of the people that want to receive a mail with the result
# - # can be used to comment out a line, this line will not be processed
#
# Notes:
# - User ScriptAdmin@domain.net needs write permissions to your path
# - For Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP we only support the UNC-path
# - Files are much faster deleted when using the server name and the local path, instead of the UNC-path
#
# Examples:
#
# SERVER1, C:\Appels.txt
# MailTo: Bob@domain.net Jake@domain.net Bobby@domain.net
# > The file 'Appels.txt' on the C-drive of SERVER1 will be removed when it's older than 30 days (default value).
# > A notification mail will be sent to Bob, Jake and Bobby afterwards with the results
#
# SERVER1, C:\Appels.txt, 0
# > The file 'Appels.txt' on the C-drive of SERVER1 will be removed every time the script runs, regardless of it's creation date.
#
# SERVER2, E:\SHARE\Target
# > All files older than 30 days will be deleted, all empty folders regardless of their creation date will be deleted to
#
# SERVER2, E:\SHARE\Target, 5
# > All files older than 5 days will be deleted, all empty folders regardless of their creation date will be deleted to
#
# SERVER2, E:\SHARE\Target, 15, k
# > All files older than 15 days will be deleted, we don't do anything with folders and leave them as is
#
# SERVER2, E:\SHARE\Target, 0
# > All files and folders will be deleted
#
# SERVER2, E:\SHARE\Target, 0, k
# > All files will be deleted, we don't do anything with folders and leave them as is
#
# \\domain.net\SHARE\Target
# > All files older than 30 days will be deleted, all empty folders regardless of their creation date will be deleted to
#
# E:\SHARE\Target, 10
# > All files older than 10 days will be deleted and all empty folders regardless of their creation date will be deleted to on the local host
# ______________________________________________________________________
```

**Code in the script:**

```
$File = (Import-Csv -Path $ImportFile -Header "A", "B", "C", "D" | Where { $_.A -NotLike "#*" })
Foreach ($_ in $File) {

# Mail recipients
if ($_.A -like "MailTo:*") {
    $MailTo += $_.A -replace "^MailTo: " | foreach {$_.Split(" ")}
    Continue # to the next object, this line doesn't need further processing for '$arrayAllPaths'
}

# UNC path
elseif ($_.A -like "\\*") {
    $Server="UNC"
    $Target=$_.A
    if(!$_.B) { 
        # if B is empty
        $OlderThanDays=$DefaultOlderThanDays
        $CleanFolders=$true
    } 
    elseif ($_.B -eq "k") {
        $OlderThanDays=$DefaultOlderThanDays
        $CleanFolders=$false
    } 
    elseif ($_.B -eq "0") {
        if (!$_.C) {
            $OlderThanDays="0"
            $CleanFolders=$true
         } 
         elseif ($_.C -eq "k") {
                $OlderThanDays="0"
                $CleanFolders=$false
         }
    } 
    else {
        if($_.C -eq "k") {
           $CleanFolders=$false
           $OlderThanDays=$_.B
        } 
        else {
        $CleanFolders=$true
        $OlderThanDays=$_.B
        }
    }
}

# Local path
elseif ($_.A -like "[A-Z]:*") {    
    $Server="$env:COMPUTERNAME"
    $Target=$_.A
     if(!$_.B) { 
        # if B is empty
        $OlderThanDays=$DefaultOlderThanDays
        $CleanFolders=$true
    } 
    elseif ($_.B -eq "k") {
        $OlderThanDays=$DefaultOlderThanDays
        $CleanFolders=$false
    } 
    elseif ($_.B -eq "0") {
        if (!$_.C) {
            $OlderThanDays="0"
            $CleanFolders=$true
         } 
         elseif ($_.C -eq "k") {
                $OlderThanDays="0"
                $CleanFolders=$false
         }
    } 
    else {
        if($_.C -eq "k") {
           $CleanFolders=$false
           $OlderThanDays=$_.B
        } 
        else {
        $CleanFolders=$true
        $OlderThanDays=$_.B
        }
    }
}

# Local host with local path
elseif ($_.A -eq $env:COMPUTERNAME) {    
    $Server="$env:COMPUTERNAME"
    $Target=$_.B
      if(!$_.C) { 
        # if C is empty
        $OlderThanDays=$DefaultOlderThanDays
        $CleanFolders=$true
    } 
    elseif ($_.C -eq "k") {
        $OlderThanDays=$DefaultOlderThanDays
        $CleanFolders=$false
    } 
    elseif ($_.C -eq "0") {
        if (!$_.D) {
            $OlderThanDays="0"
            $CleanFolders=$true
         } 
         elseif ($_.D -eq "k") {
                $OlderThanDays="0"
                $CleanFolders=$false
         }
    } 
    else {
        if($_.D -eq "k") {
           $CleanFolders=$false
           $OlderThanDays=$_.C
        } 
        else {
        $CleanFolders=$true
        $OlderThanDays=$_.C
        }
    }        
}

# Remote servers with local path
else {
    $Server=$_.A
    $Target=$_.B
      if(!$_.C) { 
        # if C is empty
        $OlderThanDays=$DefaultOlderThanDays
        $CleanFolders=$true
    } 
    elseif ($_.C -eq "k") {
        $OlderThanDays=$DefaultOlderThanDays
        $CleanFolders=$false
    } 
    elseif ($_.C -eq "0") {
        if (!$_.D) {
            $OlderThanDays="0"
            $CleanFolders=$true
         } 
         elseif ($_.D -eq "k") {
                $OlderThanDays="0"
                $CleanFolders=$false
         }
    } 
    else {
        if($_.D -eq "k") {
           $CleanFolders=$false
           $OlderThanDays=$_.C
        } 
        else {
        $CleanFolders=$true
        $OlderThanDays=$_.C
        }
    }        
}

# All server names in upper case 
if ($Server) {
    $Server = $Server.ToUpper() 
}

# Target first letters uppercase the rest in lowercase
if ($Target -like "`\`\*" ) {
    $Target = $Target.Substring(0,2)+$Target.Substring(2,1).ToUpper()+$Target.Substring(3).ToLower()
} 
else {
      $Target = $Target.Substring(0,1).ToUpper()+$Target.Substring(1,2)+$Target.Substring(3,1).ToUpper()+$Target.Substring(4).ToLower()
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your mistake is combining processing the input file with the code that actually does the cleanup job. So the first thing I would suggest would be to extract all the code that does the actual work into a cmdlet (and put it in a Powershell module file so it can be imported as necessary).

By writing a cmdlet you get documentation automatically generated, you get parsing and validation of the arguments done for you, and you can concentrate on making sure the code does what you need without having to worry about things like input file formats. You can move the examples you gave above into the `.EXAMPLES` section of the cmdlet documentation. Cmdlets can also support things like the `-WhatIf` parameter so people can test what would be removed without actually removing it.

Then your input file can simply be a powershell script that invokes the cmdlet with appropriate arguments:

```
Remove-UnwantedFiles -server SERVER1 -Path C:\Appels.txt -MailTo "Bob@domain.net","Jake@domain.net","Bobby@domain.net"
# The file 'Appels.txt' on the C-drive of SERVER1 will be removed when it's older than 30 days (default value).
# A notification mail will be sent to Bob, Jake and Bobby afterwards with the results

Remove-UnwantedFiles -server SERVER1 -Path C:\Appels.txt -MaxAge 0
# The file 'Appels.txt' on the C-drive of SERVER1 will be removed every time the script runs, regardless of it's creation date.
#

Remove-UnwantedFiles -server SERVER2 -Path E:\SHARE\Target
# > All files older than 30 days will be deleted, all empty folders regardless of their creation date will be deleted to
```

and so on...

or you can parse some csv and use it to invoke the cmdlet, or read some json or xml for the input.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. We need to work with a non-PowerShell file, so users can easily add stuff to the input file. So parsing the CSV-file is the only option I guess. But you're right, it's good to work with functions and I try to do that a lot. But with the import it's just a bit to custom to be reusable as a function..